# Azure Transcription: Missing/Incorrect caption generated by Speech to Text

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text, transcription

Anyone encounter any issues using the Azure Speech to text API with language El-gr?
The JSON output which contains the extracted text from the audio source have missing/incorrect captions.

Here a sample image where the missing caption is highlighted in Yellow and the JSON output of ASR that does not contain the said text.

[image]

This is the version that I am using Speech Services API v3.1

I already tried adding the Model for the specific locale (El-gr), but nothing works.